# In C++11, what is the fastest way to get system ticks/time?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, time, c++-chrono

My program *frequently* calls WINAPI function `timeGetTime()`, which should be replaced with usage of `<chrono>` (standard library). What is the fastest standardized way to get system time - in `float` or `int`, for my case?

I do not need tracking the date or day time, i only need precise relative ms/seconds value, which always increments. Is there any?

Comment: That would not be "system time" as that term typically means.  You want `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what "best way" means to you.

Comment: Fastest. possibly clean. Standardized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For benchmarking, you likely want [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock). It may *not* be steady - in the sense that it "always increments". The only clock that guarantees steadiness is [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

The best, steady clock would then be:

```
using ClockType = std::conditional<
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
    std::chrono::steady_clock>::type;
```

Note that `high_resolution_clock` could itself simply be an alias for `steady_clock`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need precise relative ms, you're

1. looking for system-specific
2. not wallclock

You tagged question with WinApi, I assume, this is Windows-specific.

For Windows that is [High Resolution Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx). This technology allows you to precisely calculate relative times (how much time is spent in certain function call, for example).

Comment: The reason i change timeGetTime() is because i want remove WINAPI dependency and make crossplatform solution.

Comment: Since the question is tagged winapi, it is natural to assume that you target that platform. If you'd like to add more details to the question, please edit them in.